# trouble downloading file from mysql using php form

Tags: php, mysql, download

Hi Im just at the end of developing a prototype that allows users to select some options via dynamic dropdowns and then upload a small file to mysql. I have just completed the search function that works fine and returns the results correctly. Whats had me stuck for  the last few days is allowing a user to download one of the files returned in the search result. Ive put the results into a html table and used a form for a download option, this is where I suspect the problem lies with the form because when I have messed around the file download works but when a user hits search on the previous page.

My reading has got me this far and I have viewed some questions but none seem to do the trick. Im still new to php so forgive my messy structure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the script for results_page.php

```
 if (isset ($resultts) and ($tests))

{



$sql = "SELECT p.logID, p.fileData, p.fileName, p.mimeType, p.dateCreated, t.testName,      r.resultType
    FROM result AS r 
    INNER JOIN product_logs AS p 
    ON r.resultID=p.resultID
    INNER JOIN test AS t
    ON t.testID=r.testID
    WHERE t.testName LIKE '%$tests%'
    AND r.resultType LIKE '%$resultts%'
    ORDER BY p.dateCreated DESC";

$result1= mysqli_query($sql) or die (mysqli_error());



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
$filename = $row['fileName'];
$filetype = $row['mimeType'];
$filetest = $row['testName'];
$fileresult= $row['resultType'];
$filedate=$row['dateCreated'];
$fileid=$row['logID'];
$filedata=$row['fileData'];

echo"<table>";
echo"<tr><th>File Name</th><th>File Type</th><th>Test</th><th>Result</th><th>Date</th>    <th>options</th></tr>";
echo"<tr valign=top>";
echo "</tr>";
echo"<td><'".$filename."'</td>";
echo "<td><'".$filetype."'</td>";
echo"<td><'".$filetest."'</td>";
echo"<td><'".$fileresult."'</td>";
echo"<td><'".$filedate."'</td>";
echo "<td><form action= confirm_download.php method= post</td>";
echo "<div>";
echo "<input type =hidden name=action value= '".$filename."' />";
echo "<input type=submit name=action value=download/>";
echo "<div>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</td>";

echo "</table>";
}





if ($_POST['action']=='download')
{
// Content-type must come before Content-disposition
header("Content-type: $filetype");
header("Content-disposition: attachment filename=$filename");
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($filedata));


echo $filedata;
exit();
}



}
```

Comment: database is not for storing files. Put file on your disk and store only reference to the file in your db

Comment: What is your $filename contains? Full file storage path with file name or just file name.

Comment: what exactly is your problem. do you get any error messages?

Comment: I get the index action is empty

Comment: did you notice you have `<td><'` multiple times? Maybe this is causing the data to become invisible as a broken tag?

Comment: I'll modify the table and see what happens

Comment: in that case you can also fix to close `</tr>` after echoing the `<td>`'s

Comment: I've removed the extra < but still the same problem the error is    Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\results_page3.php on line 83

Comment: ah, now i understand your problem. Next time please paste the error line along in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 inputs with name action. Remove the name=action from the submit button.

```
echo "<input type =hidden name=action value= '".$filename."' />";
echo "<input type=submit name=action value=download/>";
```

so make it like this

```
echo "<input type =hidden name=action value= '".$filename."' />";
echo "<input type=submit value=download/>";
```

**edit**

Ok, now fix your `<form>` tag. It is missing the `>` ... And it should open before the `<td>` or be closed within that td.

And close the `<div>` tag because now you are opening the tag twice, in stead of opening it once and closing it once. So the second `<div>` should become `</div>`

So this...

```
echo "<td><form action= confirm_download.php method= post</td>";
echo "<div>";
echo "<input type =hidden name=action value= '".$filename."' />";
echo "<input type=submit name=action value=download/>";
echo "<div>";
```

should become this...

```
echo "<form action= confirm_download.php method= post>";
echo "<div>";
echo "<input type =hidden name=action value= '".$filename."' />";
echo "<input type=submit name=action value=download/>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</form>";
```

**edit 2**

Ok , your new problem now is:

```
echo "<input type =hidden name=action value= '".$filename."' />";
```

this lines makes $_POST['action'] be populated with the filename.

But later on you say:

```
if ($_POST['action']=='download')
```

That will never be true (unless the filename is actually 'download'...)
You can change the if into:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made the revision unfortunately the error still shows and no file is downloaded downloaded. do you think it is the if ($_POST['action']=='download') or maybe the headers

Comment: I adjusted the form, it just sends the browser to the confirm_download.php,  I removed the, if ($_POST['action']=='download') and when search button is hit in the page prior to the results_page.php a file matching the search criteria is downloaded to the browser. Which is what I am aiming for but on the following page and only when the user hits download.Thanks for your responses it is appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing that nothing is being passed from the search results when a user selects download from the form and then on to the header.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. First off, did my suggestion work? Is the Undefined Index error gone? Is there a new error now?

Comment: sorry just thinking aloud. No still index undefined.

Comment: Which index is undefined now according to the error message? Is it another one now? ... And I have updated my answer with a new fix for you

Comment: By the way, you need something to put the first part in which you echo the `<table>` inside `if ( !isset($_POST['action'])) { }`  ... Because if action is set, then you want to download the file, and the table should then not be echoed because it will corrupt your file...

Comment: I made the revision there is no undefined index error now. Im not sure what you mean, are you saying the variables in the table?

Comment: What I am saying is, it looks to me that all the code (the `<form>` as well as the `header()` is inside 1 and the same script. And if that is the case, then first you get to see the `<form>` and you can click the file to download. But after clicking and the download start, you will still AGAIN get the `<form>` as well, and that will corrupt your file download.

Comment: Oh I see I'll have a look at that, thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: So just like the part with the `header()` has an `if(isset($_POST['action']))` around it, you will also need an `if(!isset($_POST['action']))`around the part with the `<form>`. Because when you are downloading the file you need to echo out ABSOLUTELY NOTHING ELSE along with it.

Comment: If your question is solved ... don't forget to upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: right I moved the headers to the second page confirm_download.php. It now downloads a html output of the confirm_page which includes errors on the undefined indexes in the headers $filetype, $filename, $filedata. I will look at this now. Thanks for the suggestion I should of known that.